# fscanf get string between double quotes and number

Tags: c, scanf

fscanf never got into my mind...

I am scanning /proc/partinfo  and need to get the partition number from the name.
In other words:

in a line like:

```
part22: 02200000 01000000 "kernel"
```

I need to get "kernel" (without the quotes) and 22

so far i did:

```
fscanf(fp,"%*5c%d%*c %*s %*s %s",&pnum,pname)
```

which gives me  the number 22 and "kernel" with quotes included.
how to not include them in the scanfline?

I also don't understand why %*5c  works but it should be %*4c  to skip "part" word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
char x[100] = {0}; // init not needed if you're careful enough with the return values
fscanf(fp, " \"%[^\"]\"", x); // matches quotemark, then non-quotemark chars, then the closing quotemark
// even better use e.g. %99[^\"] (i.e. bufsize-1) to prevent accidental buffer overrun
printf("->%s<-\n", x);
-->
->kernel<-
```

If that part of your code is in a loop, or follows other similar logic which you didn't show, possibly you left the prior newline unread, and `%5*c` is eating `\n p a r t`. Also possibly there's an actual character, possibly an invisible one, preceding `part`; I don't have any system with `/proc/partinfo` to check.

Comment: yep.. it was eating the previous \n

Comment: dave, that what repl.it is born to do... https://replit.com/@zibri/test-sscanf  :D

Answer (score 2):

The `scanf` family functions are known as a *poor man's parser*, because they are not very powerful, yet they can *scan*.

Here you want:

- skip anything up to a digit
- read a number
- skip anything up to a double quote
- skip the double quote
- read up to the next double quote
- skip the double quote

Using the `[]` conversion, you could write:

```
int cr = sscanf(input, "%*[^0-9]%d%*[^\"]\"%[^\"]\"", &pnum, pname);
```

It is robust to additional initial spaces, or if you read in a loop to the terminating `\n` of the previous line.

NB: I used `cr = ...` because you should **always** control the return value of an input function...

Comment: The final "skip a double quote" is mostly pointless (if you want to read following lines, you should skip everything up to the next newline), as if the trailing " is missing, you can't tell.  You should also put a maximum length on the `%[` as otherwise it might overflow its buffer.

Comment: none of these problems.. it is an embedded device with pretty strict configuration. Also I ended up re-coding everything in python which is embedded on the same platform and does not need compiling. in python I ended up doing: if(line.split(' ')[3].split('"')[1]=='kernel'): dev=line.split(' ')[0].strip(':').replace('part','/dev/mmcblk0p')